# Is there a quick way to view all associated records in MS Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

Sometimes I need to delete a duplicate record in CRM that has associations. In these cases I have to reassign these associations. The related entities menu allows me to check, one by one, whether the record has associations in any of the entities to which it is related. This forces me to scan through many related entities. Is there a quicker way to view all associations for a record?

Answer (score 4):

You could make a new record form which shows all the associated record as sub grids on a single page - might save a few clicks.

Few considerations with this approach:

- You might end up a very long form.
- You might end up a very ugly form.
- You might have to click to load sub grids depending on your version of CRM and the number of grids you have displayed (though JavaScript can be used to over come this).

Comment: This answer is better than mine, but you're leaving out some key clarifications: This technically does what he asks for, but isn't a highly user friendly solution.  Most entities have a large number of related entities, so the form would become very long (a lot of scrolling needed) and the subgrids would have to be quite small.  Also, CRM historically put some limits on number of sub-grids that will auto-load.  CRM 2011 Pre rollup 12 maxed out at 4.  Polaris Process forms maxed out at 6.  Properly qualify your answer and you'll get my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Not through the CRM UI, but if you're a SQL Wizard, you could probably come up with some fancy query to do that.  Then you could deploy an SSRS report with click through if you want to take it one step further.

You should also consider the OOB Merge for a scenario like this if you are dealing with OOB records like contacts or accounts - as this will automatically reparent child records for you (granted it will reparent all the child records to the new "master" record, but that is *usually* the intended functionality, so it works in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I created a console app that will show related GUIDs and logical names of the associated records. Currently doesn't work with Many to Many relationships because it wasn't needed for my application. It could easily be made to show links to records, but it wasn't something I needed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IOrganizationService OrganizationService = null;

        string sourceBaseUrl = "http://server/org";

        OrganizationService = CrmHelpers.GetService(sourceBaseUrl);

        //OrganizationService = CrmHelpers.GetService("sock-devcrm2015", "acs-training", "80", "http", "username", "password", "domain");

        //query for relationships for the desired record
        //need to get GUID and LogicalName
        Entity get = new Entity();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("What is the Logical Name?"));
        Console.Write("String: ");

        get.LogicalName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("What is the GUID?"));
        Console.Write("GUID: ");

        get.Id = Guid.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        RetrieveEntityRequest retrieveEntity = new RetrieveEntityRequest
        {
            EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Relationships,
            LogicalName = get.LogicalName
        };
        RetrieveEntityResponse response = (RetrieveEntityResponse)OrganizationService.Execute(retrieveEntity);

        var oneToN = response.EntityMetadata.OneToManyRelationships;
        var nToOne = response.EntityMetadata.ManyToOneRelationships;

        foreach (var relationship in oneToN)
        {
            string fetch = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
                                  <entity name='" + relationship.ReferencingEntity + @"'>
                                    <filter type='and'>
                                        <condition attribute='" + relationship.ReferencingAttribute + @"' operator='eq' value='" + get.Id.ToString() + @"' />
                                    </filter>
                                  </entity>
                                </fetch>";


            var results = OrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));

            foreach (var result in results.Entities)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("1:N || GUID: {0} LogicalName: {1}", result.Id, result.LogicalName));
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
        foreach (var relationship in nToOne)
        {
            string fetch = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
                                  <entity name='" + relationship.ReferencedEntity + @"'>
                                    <link-entity name='"+relationship.ReferencingEntity+ @"' from='"+relationship.ReferencingAttribute+@"' to='"+relationship.ReferencedAttribute+@"' alias='a'>
                                        <filter type='and'>
                                            <condition attribute='" + get.LogicalName+ @"id' operator='eq' value='" + get.Id.ToString() + @"' />
                                        </filter>
                                    </link-entity>
                                  </entity>
                                </fetch>";


            var results = OrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));

            foreach (var result in results.Entities)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("N:1 || GUID: {0} LogicalName: {1}", result.Id, result.LogicalName));
            }
        }

        Console.Write("END");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


class CrmHelpers
{
    public static IOrganizationService GetService(string baseUrl)
    {
        ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.GetCredential(new Uri(baseUrl), "negotiate");


        Uri endpoint = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc", baseUrl));
        OrganizationServiceProxy service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(endpoint, null, credentials, null);
        service.ServiceConfiguration.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());
        return service;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reassign all the associations, this would work:

- create a new record (same name/title)
- merge the 2 records
- Select the all the data from "old" record and make the new record the master (The master record will be the new one and inherit all of the subordinate record's child records.
- Since the "old" record will be deactivated you need to activate it again

You just cloned a record and the new one will have all the associations from the old one.

Comment: isn't this what my answer was - just that I included some qualifications in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

All the N:1 relationships can be found by querying the filtered view for your entity in SQL, but the fastest solution is just to use the Merge functionality built into CRM, as suggested. It doesn't delete the dupe, but it deactivates it and assigns everything you specify to the 'master' record. From there, you can delete the deactivated record.